# Repositioning the mouse pointer upon starting Windows

Tags: windows-7, mouse

I am using a windows 7 computer to run digital signage. I have the mouse hidden using nomousey. However, I need to start up with the mouse pointer located at a position on the left side of the screen, rather than the default centering of the pointer when windows starts. Can you help?